# How to configure Total Commander to show files with their extensions? 

Tags: total-commander

Please advise how to configure Total Commander that way to not show file names and their extensions in separate column but in the same one?

Comment: See here: [How to make total commander show file name with extensions?](https://superuser.com/a/329293/514463)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open *Configuration → Tabstops*. Under *Show file extensions*, choose "directly after filename".

The same setting in `wincmd.ini`:

```
[Configuration]
Aligned extension=0
```