# How to make total commander show file name with extensions?

Tags: total-commander

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure TC to show files with their extensions?](https://superuser.com/questions/238117/how-to-configure-tc-to-show-files-with-their-extensions)

Are there any settings that can make total commander show file name with extensions after it (instead of just show file name and the extension is in a separate column)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yup. Select Configuration / Options from the menu, and you'll find it here:

[image]